# Swift - Semaphore within semaphore

Tags: swift, semaphore

I am quite new at using semaphores but what my goal is to lock up a function until the other function completes running, so essentially a standard linear path.

What I have is (by excluding a lot of useless stuff):

```
function1() {
   let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
   let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

                function2()
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

 }

 function2() {
   let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
   let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

                stuff...
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

 }
```

I want function1 to wait until function2 finishes but I either get the locks not working at all or deadlocking.

Comment: You want which function to run first?

Comment: @Code The first one.

Comment: First, don't use semaphores. It's a horrible pattern, susceptible to these sorts of deadlocks. I know it feels wonderful to make asynchronous methods behave synchronously, but they made them asynchronous for a reason. Second, the reason you're deadlocking is that the shared `NSURLSession` uses a serial `NSOperationQueue` (i.e. one with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1), so the second function is calling `dispatch_semaphore_wait` on the serial queue that it eventually wants to process the response.